# What is the eclipse directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Windows 7 and can't seem to find out what the eclipse directory is. I do know what a directory is though.
If I save eclipse in my downloads folder would it look like this:

```
C:\Users\*****\Downloads\eclipse-mars-67\eclipse
```

I need to know where the eclipse.ini file is, and nothing I'm reading is helping.

When I run eclipse it says:

> Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit exit code=13

Comment: Did you unzip the file somewhere?

Comment: Eclipse directory is the very directory where you unzip Eclipse into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't "install" on windows like a standard application. Wherever you `unzip`d the eclipse directory to is where it's installed. Try examining your `Eclipse` shortcut that you launch with, it should have the directory in there.